# How can I get no. of Swap operations to form the 2nd Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have got two arrays with same elements... (But in different order)
e.g 1 2 12 9 7 15 22 30
and 1 2 7 12 9 20 15 22

how many swaps operations are needed to form the 2nd array from the first.?

I have tried taking no. of different elements for each index and dividing the result by 2 but that isn't fetching me the right answer...

Comment: And how many swaps required in given example?

Comment: What is required? What are constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One classic algorithm seems to be permutation cycles (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation#Cycle_notation). The number of swaps needed equals the total number of elements subtracted by the number of cycles.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 5 4 3 1

Start with 1 and follow the cycle:
1 down to 2, 2 down to 5, 5 down to 1.

1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 1
3 -> 4 -> 3
```

We would need to swap index 1 with 5, then index 5 with 2; as well as index 3 with index 4. Altogether 3 swaps or `n - 2`. We subtract `n` by the number of cycles since cycle elements together total `n` and each cycle represents a swap less than the number of elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

1) re-index elements from 0 to n-1. In your example, arrayA becomes 0..7 and arrayB becomes 0 1 4 2 3 7 5 6.

2) sort the second array using your swapping algorithm and count the number of operations.

Comment: I guess this only works when the elements of the array are 1,2,3....n ..
it won't work in the example given in my case.. :/

Comment: @VatsalPrakash it perfectly works: step 1 is to re-index!

Comment: Ohh... Thanxxx.. (y) :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit naive, but I think you can use recursion as follows (pseudo code):

```
function count_swaps(arr1, arr2):
    unless both arrays contain the same objects return false
    if arr1.len <= 1 return 0
    else
        if arr1[0] == arr2[0] return count_swaps(arr1.tail, arr2.tail)
        else
            arr2_tail = arr2.tail
            i = index_of arr1[0] in arr2_tail
            arr2_tail[i] = arr2[0]
            return 1+count_swaps(arr1.tail, arr2_tail)
```

Here's a ruby implementation:

```
require 'set'

def count_swaps(a1, a2)
    raise "Arrays do not have the same objects: #{a1} #{a2}" unless a1.length == a2.length && Set[*a1]==Set[*a2]
    return count_swap_rec(a1, a2)
end

def count_swap_rec(a1, a2)
    return 0 if a1.length <= 1
    return count_swaps(a1[1..-1], a2[1..-1]) if a1[0] == a2[0]
    a2_tail = a2[1..-1]
    a2_tail[a2_tail.find_index(a1[0])] = a2[0]
    return 1 + count_swaps(a1[1..-1], a2_tail)
end
```